# Why am I getting variable not found errors?

Tags: vb.net

I am getting undeclared variable errors with my code and I don't know why! The variables are declared above, but when being used, they are not found! The error in question occurs on the variables with two stars

```
    If hour >= 10 Then
        Dim hourAnn = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("_" + hour.ToString)
    Else
        Dim hourAnn = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("_0" + hour.ToString)
    End If

    If minute >= 10 Then
        Dim minuteAnn = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("_" + minute.ToString)
    Else
        Dim minuteAnn = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("_" + minute.ToString)
    End If

    'Ann Type
    If annType = 1 Then
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.nowApproachPlatform, AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)  'The train now approaching platform
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(platformAnn, AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)                       'x
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.isThe, AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)                'is the
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(**hourAnn**, AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)                '<hour>
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(**minuteAnn**, AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)                '<min>
```

Comment: I cant see any stars, but an `If` statement creates a new block scope, so `hourAnn` and `minuteAnn` go out of scope immediately after they are declared

Comment: Stars are in the `If` statement at the bottom :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variables are only known in the scope they are created.

If you create a variable in an `if`-structure, they are only known inside that `if`. Same counts for `functions`, `for`-loops and any other "containing" structures.

Solution for your code:

```
Dim hourAnn = ""
 If hour >= 10 Then
        hourAnn = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("_" + hour.ToString)
    Else
        hourAnn = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("_0" + hour.ToString)
    End If

Dim minuteAnn = ""
If minute >= 10 Then
    minuteAnn = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("_" + minute.ToString)
Else
    minuteAnn = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("_" + minute.ToString)
End If
```

Want to learn more? [Read here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx)

Comment: @DavidWheatley Please consider marking my answer as "the answer" and upvote it, if it helped you.

Comment: I have to wait a few minutes first, it won't let me right away!